# Wordpress block editor template parts not saving

Tags: block-editor

I am having trouble editing my header and footer template parts on wp block editor (child theme 2022). I keep getting an error message "saving failed".

I am building the site with elementor(not a pro version) and using the wp block editor for the header and footer. I had no problem creating it- but I cant save any changes I want to add now.

The error message is recent problem. I cant add any template parts as well- there seems to be something wrong with the block editor
Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: Do you receive the same errors when using 2022 itself? What about other themes? Does it work with Elementor disabled? Is Elementor compatible with block themes? You may need to ask its author.

Comment: have you checked your browsers dev tools console for error messages or your servers PHP error log?

Comment: The console is coming clean- I have no errors. And elementor is compatible with block themes- I have done so on other sites without any errors, as well as this site functioned until now.

Comment: and the response in the network tab from the REST API isn't malformed or invalid HTML? Is this only the site editor or all block editor related interfaces?

Comment: yes its valid. Just the site editor (created header and footer with it)